# What common developments are there to solve $1+x=x^a$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

I am facing the trinominal equation $1+x=x^a$ where $a$ is not necessarely an integer, but some positive real. Are there some common **series** developments of functions $x=V(a)$ that one can solve the equatios via $1+V(a)=V(a)^a$.

Comment: Do you only want the positive solution?  For instance, for $a=-1$, the two solutions are $\frac{1}{2}(-1 \pm \sqrt{5})$.  Worse maybe, for $a = 5/2$, the three roots are the three roots of $x^5 - x^2 - 2x - 1$, one of which is positive and real and the other two are complex with negative real part?

Comment: For $a=1$ it is also a bit difficult to solve, so whatever the solution it will diverge when $a\rightarrow 1$. (also you only want positive real solutions?)

Comment: If you only want to the positive real root, you can restrict to $a>1$.  For $0 < a < 1$ there is no positive real root.

Answer (score 6):

If you plot $1+x$ and $x^a$ it will be clear that , for $0 \leqslant x$, 
there is one, and only one, real solution iff $1<a$.
That can be proven rigorously by analytical considerations.

Then, if you consider the equality witten as $$f(x)=1+x-x^a=0$$
you can apply the Newton-Raphson method and find a sequence
which will approximate the root.
[image: 1+x-xa]

*----  Addendum    ----*

Following your comment, consider that you can write a series expansion of the $f(x)$ above around $x=1$, as: $$\begin{gathered}
  f(x) = \left( {2 + \left( {x - 1} \right)} \right) - \left( {1 + \left( {x - 1} \right)} \right)^{\;a}  =  \hfill \\
   = \left( {2 + \left( {x - 1} \right)} \right) - \sum\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,k} {\left( \begin{gathered}
  a \\ 
  k \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)\left( {x - 1} \right)^{\;k} }  =  \hfill \\
   = 1 - \left( {a - 1} \right)\left( {x - 1} \right) - \sum\limits_{2\, \leqslant \,k} {\left( \begin{gathered}
  a \\ 
  k \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)\left( {x - 1} \right)^{\;k} }  \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$

Comment: @j4nbur53, Newton method (even the simple "secant" method)  will give a sequence converging (quite fast) to $x_0$. Since the function and its 1st (and even 2nd) derivatives are quite simple, the recurrence governing the sequence is also quite simple.

Comment: @j4nbur53, well, it depends from what you are actually looking for (which is not clear).  I added a possible series development around $x=1$ to my answer.

Comment: Are you also using $a=3/2$ in your right-hand image?  It seems to be labeled as generic with respect to $a$, but that wouldn't yield a single curve.

Comment: @EricTowers: yes, that is just an example for a particular value of $a$ ($a=3/2$).

Comment: I have renamed my function that I want to get calculated via series from $f$ to $V$ so that no confusion arises with here and also elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use the [Lagrange inversion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_reversion) (also known as series reversion).  Your problem is the [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_reversion#Example) there.  Applying that example here, the root of $x^a - x - 1 = 0$ is
$$ x = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{a k}{k} \frac{(-1)^{(a-1)k+1}}{(a-1)k+1}  $$

However, this won't work.  First, the radius of convergence of the series is upper bounded by $1$, so isn't large enough to include the $x$s you actually want.  Second, this series does not converge for $a> 1$.

But maybe we can apply series reversion differently...

Solve for $a$:
$$ a = \frac{\ln(1+x)}{\ln x}  \text{.}  $$

Write this as a series.  The function $\frac{\ln(1+x)}{\ln x}$ has a simple pole at $x=1$, so we expand in Laurent series around $x = 1$:
$$ a = \frac{\ln 2}{x-1} + \frac{1 + \ln 2}{2} + \frac{3 - 2 \ln(2)}{24}(x-1) + \frac{2 \ln 2 - 3}{48} (x-1)^2 + \cdots  \text{.}  $$

Now apply series reversion:
$$ x = 1 + \frac{\ln 2}{a} + \frac{(1+ \ln 2)\ln 2}{2} \frac{1}{a^2} + \frac{(4 (\ln 2)^2 + 15 \ln 2 + 6)\ln 2}{24} \frac{1}{a^3} + \cdots  \text{.}  $$

Carefully doing the above and reducing the final series to numerical constants and up to order $a^{-12}$, we have
$$
\hat{x} = 1 +\frac{0.693147180559945 \dots}{a} + \frac{0.586800097239073 \dots}{a^2} + \frac{0.529074037503684 \dots}{a^3} + \frac{0.491400591502458 \dots}{a^4} + \frac{0.464233780296217 \dots}{a^5} + \frac{0.443382411364081 \dots}{a^6} + \frac{0.426681599568780 \dots}{a^7} + \frac{0.412885047737368 \dots}{a^8} + \frac{0.401217324466756 \dots}{a^9} + \frac{0.391166922812855 \dots}{a^{10}} + \frac{0.382380685540601 \dots}{a^{11}} + \frac{0.374605695976650 \dots}{a^{12}} + \cdots
$$

We analyze the discrepancy, $\hat{x}+1 - \hat{x}^a$, hoping to get zero.  Plotting the log of the discrepancy versus $a$, we get

[image: Log Discrepancy]

This behaves as expected: for large $a$, the last series "converges" quickly and for small $a$, not so quickly.  (Converges is in quotes because there is no reason to expect this asymptotic series to *actually* converge.)

Comment: Series reversion refers to this http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeriesReversion.html , right? Interesting!

Comment: Yes, that page is describing the same thing I am using.

Comment: Can it be summed for $a=1$ for instance with a Shanks transformation?

Comment: @OscarLanzi : Certainly, the Shanks transformation could be used to accelerate convergence of finite initial segments of this series.  I don't see any way to *sum* the series by this method...

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Euler inspired by Lambert has figured out a series already in the past. I stepped over the Euler solution when researching for this question [here](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/a/5324/4900). The development of the series is repeated in this paper [here](http://www.maplesoft.com/applications/download.aspx?SF=4204/lambert_w_function.pdf).

Lets specialize the solution of Euler to the given Problem. The equation that Euler solves is $x^α-x^β = (α-β)*v*x^{α+β}$. The aforementioned paper mentions a series development by Euler, which is based on Lambert, which reads as follows:

$x^n = 1 + n*v + \frac{1}{2}*n*(n+α+β)*v^2$
$\quad \quad + \frac{1}{6}*n*(n+α+2*β)*(n+2*α+β)*v^3$
$\quad \quad + \frac{1}{24}*n*(n+α+3*β)*(n+2*α+2*β)*(n+3*α+β)*v^4$
$\quad \quad + \, etc..$

We can divide both sides of Eulers equation by $x^β$ and get after rearrangement $1 + (α-β)*v*x^α = x^{α-β}$. Now set $β=1-a$, $α=1$ and $v=1/a$ and we get our trinomial. We can use $n=1$ and do get:

$x = 1 + 1/a + \frac{1}{2}*(3-a)*1/a^2$
$\quad \quad + \frac{1}{6}*(4-2*a)*(4-a)*1/a^3$
$\quad \quad + \frac{1}{24}*(5-3*a)*(5-2*a)*(5-a)*1/a^4$
$\quad \quad + \, etc..$

The convergence is pretty bad, since for example each summand has in the same potency the parameter $a$ both in the numerator as well in the denomerator. But it wurks!

```
A    1.5        2          2.5        3 
a_0  1.0000000  1.0000000  1.0000000  1.0000000 
a_1  0.6666667  0.5000000  0.4000000  0.3333333 
a_2  0.3333333  0.1250000  0.0400000  0.0000000 
a_3  0.1234568  0.0000000 -0.0160000 -0.0123457 
a_4  0.0288066 -0.0078125  0.0000000  0.0041152 
a_5  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.0017920  0.0000000 
a_6 -0.0033531  0.0009766 -0.0004224 -0.0006097 
a_7 -0.0013209  0.0000000 -0.0001690  0.0002540 
a_8  0.0000000 -0.0001526  0.0001132  0.0000000 
X    2.1475893  1.6180115  1.4253138  1.3247472 
1+X  3.1475893  2.6180115  2.4253138  2.3247472 
X^A  3.1472181  2.6179611  2.4253600  2.3248721
```

Other manipulations give other series,
maybe a much better series could be developed.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Under certain conditions (see [Fixed-point iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_iteration))

You can rewrite $x=x^a-1$, in which $\phi(x)=x^a-1$. A recursive solution is given by 
$$x_{n+1}=\phi(x_n).$$